# How to get localized game news from Steam Web API?

Tags: api, steam

The Steam Web API has an ISteamNews interface with a [GetNewsForApp](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetNewsForApp_.28v0002.29) method that returns the latest game announcements, example request

```
GET http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamNews/GetNewsForApp/v0002/?appid=570&count=3&maxlength=0&format=json&feeds=steam_community_announcements
```

And everything works fine, but the news are only in English, and I can't find how to change it.

Some methods have an optional l= parameter, but it does not work for news, although the steam client displays localized news and, according to the [documentation](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/marketing/event_tools#4), there is full support for localizations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain the documentation you're linking is for publishing a news event for Steam partners/developers.

When running the SupportedAPIList call from this documentation: [Steam Web API News Documentation](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#Interfaces_and_method:)

These are the parameters the API currently accepts for non-publishers/devs without an API Key:

{"name":"GetNewsForApp","version":2,"httpmethod":"GET","parameters":

{"name":"appid","type":"uint32","optional":false,"description":"AppID to retrieve news for"}

{"name":"maxlength","type":"uint32","optional":true,"description":"Maximum length for the content to return, if this is 0 the full content is returned, if it's less then a blurb is generated to fit."}

{"name":"enddate","type":"uint32","optional":true,"description":"Retrieve posts earlier than this date (unix epoch timestamp)"}

{"name":"count","type":"uint32","optional":true,"description":"# of posts to retrieve (default 20)"}

{"name":"feeds","type":"string","optional":true,"description":"Comma-separated list of feed names to return news for"}

{"name":"tags","type":"string","optional":true,"description":"Comma-separated list of tags to filter by (e.g. 'patchnodes')"}]}]}

You will have to play around with these parameters to filter the proper responses. Just remember that the Steam API allows only 100,000 requests within a 24 hour period or your IP/API key may be subject to ban or withdrawal. Unfortunately at this time I have been unable to locate what sorts of queries the parameters feeds and tags accept.

Goodluck